# wrapping Wordpress text content in div

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have an Wordpress site using bootstrap framework. I have content (written in the admin posts panel) which contains images and text. I am trying to wrap the text content in `row` and `col-md-10` tags (and leaving the images alone)

It is brought into my single.php page

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

I have tried playing around with preg_replace to the effect of

```
<?php
     $content = preg_replace('/<row>(.*?)<\/row>/', '', get_the_content());
     $content = wpautop($content);
     echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: sounds like this is just a regex question and how to replace `<row>` with `<div class="row">`? at a minimum, you need to show the contents of `$content` and what you want to replace with what.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use wordpress shortcodes for this? Regardless there simply isn't enough shown for sample input or expected results.... provide a [mcve]

Comment: Not very familiar with Wordpress shortcodes. I don't have full control over what content is put in. <?php the_content(); ?> brings it all in as is, I just want to identify what isn't in <img> tags and wrap in .row tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code. You will have to put it in your **functions.php**. What it does is that it searches for all the images and then wraps the content in divs leaving images intact. **I have tested it.** And it is working fine even if you have no images.

```
function sr_wrap_content_in_div( $content )
{
    $contents = explode("<img", $content);
    foreach($contents as $content)
    {
        $before_tag = strstr($content, '/>', true); 
        $after_tag = strstr($content, '/>');
        if( $before_tag == '' && $after_tag == '' )
        {
            echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-10">'; // change it later if you need to
            echo $content;
            echo '</div></div>';
        } else if( $after_tag == '/> ' )
        {
            echo '<img';
            echo $before_tag;
            echo '/>';
        } else 
        {
            echo '<img';
            echo $before_tag;
            echo '/>';
            echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-10">'; // change here too.
            echo substr($after_tag, 2);
            echo '</div></div>';
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'sr_wrap_content_in_div' );
```

Comment: Follow-up question/issue though, It creates and wraps empty divs/gaps between images. As well putting row and col-md-10 in the same class messes with the bootstrap functionality. I tried changing it to  ... echo '<div class="row"<div class=col-md-10">' to get it wrapped separately like traditional bootstrap framework, but the rows get put inside the previous rows. (A row inside a row, inside a row, inside a row, etc)

Comment: Check this out.

Comment: Oh I see what I was missing, Thanks a bunch for all the help